# Restkit 2 JSON example

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm searching for a good tutorial for Restkit 2. Everywhere I'm seeing, they are talking about Object Mapping. Is it not possible to use Restkit and obtain a JSON as string and then use the JSON directly.

Comment: Did you read the docs on the RestKit GitHub page?

Comment: I did not go through it completely, I'm completely new to ios development & restkit, I'm continually searching for it

Comment: Don't use RestKit to just get JSON. Use AFNetworking instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking Does the Job,

AFNetworking can be installed using cocoapads as shown [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking),

A sample request using AFNetworking:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.ez-point.com/search"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization" ];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[jsonDic setValue:@"UJO526" forKey:@"search_text"  ];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSArray *searchResults = JSON;
            if ([searchResults count] == 1){
                id result = [searchResults objectAtIndex:0];
                double latitude = [[result valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
                double longitude = [[result valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
                NSString *ezPoint = [result valueForKey:@"value"];
                NSString *tags = [result valueForKey:@"tags"];

                [self setAnnotation:latitude  ForLongitude:longitude withEZPoint:ezPoint WithTags:tags];
            }
        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        }
 ];
[operation start];
```